# Calling Outlook Macro from Excel VBA with Multiple Arguments

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am attempting to call an Outlook macro from Excel and pass two or more arguments to it.  I have successfully passed 1 argument with the following code:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

Dim Arg1 As String
Dim Arg2 As String

Arg1 = "A"
Arg2 = "B"

OutApp.TempTest (Arg1)
```

where TempTest is the Outlook procedure.  I've attempted to add the 2nd argument by replacing the last line of code with

```
OutApp.TempTest (Arg1, Arg2)
```

but as soon as I finish typing I get a Compile error: Expected: =

I've seen posts where someone is passing to Excel or Access and uses the Run method, but Outlook does not support that.

Comment: Just remove the parentheses. http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/10/26/a-quick-tip-working-with-arrays-with-unknown-bounds/

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.

"Just remove the parentheses." –  [Doug Glancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy)